# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended. What to do?

Tags: sql, oracle

```
Select A.CUST_ID, A.CUST_FNAME 
From BANK_CUSTOMER A
Where A.CUST_TYPE=’IND’
    And A.CUST_ID in (select CUST_ID from BANK_CUST_CONTACT where CONTACT_TYPE =’OFFICE’);
```

I am getting the error

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly
>   ended

Comment: If you have a semicolon at the end, remove it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities

1. Remove the `;` at the end & try
2. There could be special character like new line

Otherwise there is no problem with the query

Answer (score 0):

You are using *fancy single quotes*:

```
Select A.CUST_ID, A.CUST_FNAME 
From BANK_CUSTOMER A
Where A.CUST_TYPE=’IND’                                  --> here
    And A.CUST_ID in (select CUST_ID 
                      from BANK_CUST_CONTACT 
                      where CONTACT_TYPE =’OFFICE’);     --> here
```

Use *normal* ones:

```
Select A.CUST_ID, A.CUST_FNAME 
From BANK_CUSTOMER A
Where A.CUST_TYPE='IND'                                  --> here
    And A.CUST_ID in (select CUST_ID 
                      from BANK_CUST_CONTACT 
                      where CONTACT_TYPE = 'OFFICE');     --> here
```

That usually happens when you copy/paste code you write from MS Word or a similar text editor.